# Binding ajax page in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I tried coding with angular.js 1.5.

```
<div class="container clearfix" id="mainMenu" ng-controller="MainMenuController as mainMenu">
    <ul class="menu clearfix" ng-init="tab = 'ant'">
        <li class="menu1" ng-class="{menu_active:mainMenu.isSelected('ant')}">
            <a href="#!/antTalkList" ng-click="mainMenu.selectTab('ant')">개미생톡</a></li>
        <li class="menu2" ng-class="{menu_active:mainMenu.isSelected('expert')}">
            <a href="#!/expertTalkList" ng-click="mainMenu.selectTab('expert')">전문가생톡</a></li>
        <li class="menu3" ng-class="{menu_active:mainMenu.isSelected('club')}">
            <a href="#!/clubTalkList" ng-click="mainMenu.selectTab('club')">둥지생톡</a></li>
        <li class="menu4" ng-class="{menu_active:mainMenu.isSelected('finance')}">
            <a href="#!/finance" ng-click="mainMenu.selectTab('finance')">시황생톡</a></li>
        <li class="menu5" ng-class="{menu_active:mainMenu.isSelected('shopping')}">
            <a href="#!/shopping" ng-click="mainMenu.selectTab('shopping')">생톡쇼핑</a></li>
        <li class="menu6" ng-class="{menu_active:mainMenu.isSelected('more')}">
            <a href="#!/settings" ng-click="mainMenu.selectTab('more')">더보기</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="combine_content" id="content-area" ng-bind-html="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see, I declared `ng-bind-html="content"` and this will be replaced that the menu is selected.

So I codeded `app.js` like this. 
each menu's html code stored `tabViews[tabName]` from http ajax call.
When the menu is selected, then `mainMenu.content` stores `tabViews[tabName]`.

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('stocktalkApp', []);
    app.controller('MainMenuController', function($scope, $http){

    this.tabViews = [];
    this.tab='ant';

     $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "ant/view"
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.mainMenu.tabViews['ant'] = response;
            $scope.content = $scope.mainMenu.tabViews[$scope.mainMenu.tab];
        }, function myError(response) {
        });
     $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "expert/view"
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.mainMenu.tabViews['expert'] = response;
        }, function myError(response) {
        });  

    this.selectTab =  function(tabName){
        this.tab = tabName;
        this.content = this.tabViews[this.tab];
    };
    this.isSelected = function(tabName){
        return tabName === this.tab;
    }
});
})();
```

But, the error was occurred `angular.js:13920Error: [$sce:unsafe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$sce/unsafe`.

How can I show the page in html?

Updated :

I have updated my code in ajax call, `response` to `response.data` and declared function but same error occurred again.

This is updated html code
`<div class="combine_content" id="content-area" ng-bind-html="makeTrusted(content)"></div>`

and this is my `app.js` code

```
$scope.makeTrusted = function(htmlCode) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(htmlCode);
}

 $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "ant/view"
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        $scope.mainMenu.tabViews['ant'] = response.data;
        $scope.content = $scope.mainMenu.tabViews[$scope.mainMenu.tab];
    }, function myError(response) {
    });
 $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "expert/view"
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        $scope.mainMenu.tabViews['expert'] = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject the `$sce` service in the controller and `trustAsResourceUrl` the url there

**Controller**

```
App.controller('AppController', ['$http', '$scope', '$sce',
    function($http, $scope, $sce) {
     $scope.makeTrusted= function(html_code) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(html_code);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="combine_content" id="content-area" ng-bind-html="makeTrusted(content)">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan, but $sce can't find in my code, where should I declare the `$sce`?

Comment: @MinkyuKim You need to add it to the controller, check the updated answer

Comment: Yes, I created a new Plunk, but I have been used first time, if any problem, please tell me.  https://plnkr.co/edit/9mit8WuiWe9mjumi1GkB?p=info